# Conditional Formatting based on Number of Words

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using Google sheets where I am highlighting duplicate cells in Column B.

This Conditional Formatting Rule (Single Color) applied to Range B3:B3727 works just fine:

```
=countif($B$3:$B3,$B3)>1
```

However now I do not want an exact match.

Words like **Atom Boss Ltd.** should be matched with **Atom Boss Limited**. Similar **Holistic Co** should be matched with **Holistic Co Group** and so on.

Is there a way I can rewrite this to match my requirement? What do you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You could use wildcards and concatenation. But you have to decide where to put that wildcard as "Ltd." does not match "Limited. but "L*." does match "Limited.".

See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en